# Find Minimum (grouped) timestamp

Tags: qgis

I have a list of data points with timestamps in the format:

row: Object ID, timestamp

I would like to find the minimum timestamp grouped for each object id, something like:
minimum(timestamp, object ID)

this format works when I have other data formats. Is this because my timestamp is in the format Date&Time?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are more solutions for your question.

1. DB Manager

Turn on **DB Manager** plugin and open **DB Manager** from the menu **Database/DB Manager**.

In the left side open **Virtual Layers/Project Layers** you should see your table.

Select the spanner icon to open Query tab.

On the Query tab insert your SQL query:

```
SELECT "Object ID", min(timestamp) FROM your_table GROUP BY 1;
```

Press **Execute** button, check **Load as new Layer** and press **Load** button. This way you get a one row for each ID.

Here is a sample with my data:

[image]

2. Field Calculator

Open the table of your layer and open field calculator.

Create a new **Virtual** field

The expression:

```
minimum(  "datetime" , group_by:=  "id" )
```

This way you get in each row the minimum data. Here is my example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyqgis:

```py
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('testdata_date')[0] #Change layer name to match your data
fieldlist = ['objectid', 'date'] #group field, date field. Change to match your data

data = [[f[fieldname] for fieldname in fieldlist] for f in lyr.getFeatures()]
data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), reverse=True) #Sort by objectid and date
d = {key:val for key,val in data} #Create a dictionary with objectid
#as key and date as value. Since the data is sorted so that the earliestTime
#date is last that is what the dictionary value will be

for key, value in d.items():
    print("Earliest date for {0} is: {1}".format(key, value.toPyDate().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
```

[image]